# Echo inside an element attribute?

Tags: php, iframe

I was just wondering if it is possible to put a php echo inside an iframe? something like this:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $dyn; ?>" width="800" height="500" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

and if not, what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Did you encounter a specific problem?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. yes, the <?php echo function doesn't work at all as soon as I put inside the iframe but it does work fine when it is outside of the iframe. any suggestions?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not descriptive enough to recommend anything. HTML output? Error messages? Odd behaviour?

Comment: no errors at all... in fact the iframe opens my server's homepage when I echo php inside it!!

Comment: No errors at all, or no enabled `error_reporting` as usual? You were asked for HTML output as well.

Comment: then I guess as usual!! I don't know how to output error in a html file!!!

Answer (score 1):

The way PHP works is that work is done behind the scenes, before the HTML is even sent, so by the time that you actually send the full data to the user, it's parsed into what should be given to the browser.

That is to say, when for example

```
<?php
    $dyn = "index.html";
?>

<iframe src="<?php echo $dyn; ?>" width="800" height="500" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

By the time that the server breaks it all down, the browser will only ever see

```
<iframe src="index.html" width="800" height="500" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

That's why you can use HTML and PHP on the same page, because the server parses the PHP before it's sent to the browser, so you end up just sending Text/HTML to the end location. Echo is simply the means of telling PHP, "Instead of just doing this, show the user this result.", and it builds it around the HTML you already have present.

Comment: I am not being funny here but I just wish instead of throwing all that information which is freely available all over the net you could go straight to the point and say/metion something related to the issue and NOT going round the corner 20 times and then leave without answering the question

Comment: The question was, "I was just wondering if it is possible to put a php echo inside an iframe? something like this:", and I gave the answer that yes, it is, and the reasoning why. How is that going around the corner and not answering the question?

Comment: I know we're not suppose to have an argument here but if you could show me a single bit in your comment that says "yes" and the reasoning that "yes" then I will eat my hat!!!! you just making me feel like I can't read and write or I'm some sort of a blind for god sake!!!

Comment: "That's why you can use HTML and PHP on the same page, because the server parses the PHP before it's sent to the browser, so you end up just sending Text/HTML to the end location." <--- Long winded I'll grant, but is a yes.